# Budgie Panel 100% CPU usage and black / not visible

Tags: budgie

I recently added a System Monitor applet using budgie desktop settings. Since then the panel has 100% CPU utilization and is seems to be drawn but fully black and unusable.

How can I access or reset the settings? It is super hard to find documentation on this. Was this developed specifically for budgie or does it also exist under a different name?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reset the settings with

```
budgie-panel --replace --reset
```

Comment: Thanks for detailing this Christian.  However that command didn't work for me.  It would hang and after pressing ctrl-c the top panel would disappear completely.  I had to use:  "nohup budgie-panel --reset --replace &"